# How to get the number of data that are retrieving through response.body?

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart, httprequest

How can I get the number of data that are retrieving through response.body?
I tried many methods including below one to get that number. But non of them worked out pretty well.

```
var convertJsonToData = json.decode(response.body);
data = convertJsonToData;
data.forEach((element) => touristCount++);
```

The variable touristCount is declared and initialized to 0 at the beginning of this dart file. 
Here are my codes.

**AdminMenu.dart**

```
String apiurl = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/retrieveTourists/";
List data;
var touristCount = 0;
```

```
class _AdminMenuState extends State<AdminMenu> {
  @override
  // var touristCount = 2;
  // _AdminMenuState({this.touristCount});

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getTouristCount(context);
  }

  void getTouristCount(BuildContext context) async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(apiurl), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        var convertJsonToData = json.decode(response.body);
        data = convertJsonToData;
        data.forEach((element) => touristCount++);
      });
    }
  }
..................
..................
....................
```

**AuthController.php**

```
public function retrieveTourists(){
        $user = tourists::all();
        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

**api.php**

```
Route::get('/retrieveTourists','Api\AuthController@retrieveTourists');
```

All I want is to display the count at "Text" here.

```
Widget buttonSection1 = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.black38),
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(8)),
  ),
  child: Column(    
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.people, 'Guides'),      
      Text(touristCount.toString()),  <----------------------------------- Display the count???   
    ],
  ),
);
```

Can someone help me with this? :)

Answer (score 0):

If your incoming data is an **array**, you can use the **length** property to get the number of data, like this:

```js
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        var convertJsonToData = json.decode(response.body);
         touristCount = convertJsonToData.length
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that! We can get this thing done by passing the touristCount variable as a parameter to the buttonSection1 widget

```
Widget buttonSection1(int num_guides){
  return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.black38),
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(8)),
  ),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.people, 'Guides'),
      Text(num_guides.toString()),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Calling the widget in build widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
            title: Text("Admin Menu"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
            ],
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [    
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [                       
                    buttonSection1(touristCount),
                    .....................
                    .....................
```